# Why is this laravel phone validation rule not working in this case?

Tags: laravel-validation

I have this code to register a user:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'first_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
            'last_name' => 'required|string|min:2|max:255',
            'mobile_phone_number' => 
 required|string|min:11|max:15|unique:users|phone:NG,mobile',
            'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|confirmed|min:12',
            'terms' => 'required',
        ]);

        Auth::login($user = User::create([
            'first_name' => $request->first_name,
            'last_name' => $request->last_name,
            'mobile_phone_number' => $request->mobile_phone_number,
            'email' => $request->email,
            'password' => Hash::make($request->password),
        ]));

        $request->user()->markTermsAsAccepted();
        event(new Registered($user));
        return redirect('/verify-email');
        
    }
```

My validation rules for mobile phone number includes this: 'phone:NG,mobile' to specify that only numbers from the specific locale are acceptable.

This happens to work.

I now have this code in another project:

```
  public function create(array $input)
    {
        Validator::make($input, [
            'first_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'last_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'mobile_phone_number' => ['required', 'string', 'min:11', 'max:15', 'unique:users', 'phone:NG,mobile'],
            'password' => $this->passwordRules(),
            'terms' => Jetstream::hasTermsAndPrivacyPolicyFeature() ? ['required', 'accepted'] : '',
        ])->validate();

        return User::create([
            'first_name' => $input['first_name'],
            'last_name' => $input['last_name'],
            'email' => $input['email'],
            'mobile_phone_number' => $input['mobile_phone_number'],
            'password' => Hash::make($input['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

But this doesn't work. I get this error: BadMethodCallException Method Illuminate\Validation\Validator::validatePhone does not exist.

Yes, there's no 'Phone' validation rule in the Laravel docs and I'm wondering how come the first code works and the second doesn't.

Comment: I'm such an idiot, I forgot I used a package for that to work in the first case.

Comment: May I ask what package is that? `phone` validation is definitely not available in Laravel validation rules. And in the first syntax, if you throw any string into the validation stirng, there will be no error whatsoever.

Comment: I used this package: https://github.com/Propaganistas/laravel-phone